# Need to know the role of && in this query

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Could anyone provide the explanation of the below query and why there is `&&` usage in this query? What will be the output of this query?

```
SELECT 
    ((TRUNC(SYSDATE - (&&days)) - TO_DATE('01-JAN-1970')) * 86400000) - 7200000 AS ts, 
    to_char(SYSDATE - (&&days), 'YYYYMMDD') || '_pt.txt' as pt_filenm from dual;
```

Comment: Hi new user.  "from dual" is an ORACLE syntax (IIRC), not a Microsoft Sql Server syntax/object.  Please remove "sql-server" from your tags and add oracle.  Proper "tags" will help you get an answer sooner than later.  Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unable to change my tag could you suggest me how to do it

Answer (score 2):

It is about Oracle's SQL*Plus substitution variables.

- if you use `&`, you'll be prompted to enter variable value every time
- if you use `&&`, you won't be prompted to use a variable whose value is already entered

Here's an example. I'm setting default date format and selecting today's date:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select trunc(sysdate) l_today from dual;

L_TODAY
----------
13.01.2019
```

Now, why we're here. First, I'm using only one `&` and will be prompted twice to enter number of days I'm subtracting from today's date:

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate - &days) l_one,
  2         to_char(trunc(sysdate - &days), 'yyyy-mm-dd') l_two
  3  from dual;
Enter value for days: 5
old   1: select trunc(sysdate - &days) l_one,
new   1: select trunc(sysdate - 5) l_one,
Enter value for days: 5
old   2:        to_char(trunc(sysdate - &days), 'yyyy-mm-dd') l_two
new   2:        to_char(trunc(sysdate - 5), 'yyyy-mm-dd') l_two

L_ONE      L_TWO
---------- ----------
08.01.2019 2019-01-08
```

But, if I use `&&`, I'll be prompted only once:

```
SQL> select trunc(sysdate - &&days) l_one,
  2         to_char(trunc(sysdate - &&days), 'yyyy-mm-dd') l_two
  3  from dual;
Enter value for days: 10
old   1: select trunc(sysdate - &&days) l_one,
new   1: select trunc(sysdate - 10) l_one,
old   2:        to_char(trunc(sysdate - &&days), 'yyyy-mm-dd') l_two
new   2:        to_char(trunc(sysdate - 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd') l_two

L_ONE      L_TWO
---------- ----------
03.01.2019 2019-01-03

SQL>
```

So, it saves you some time and makes errors less possible.

---

Note that - if you use `&&` and run the same code once again, you won't be prompted for the variable's value - it'll automatically be re-used:

```
SQL> /
old   1: select trunc(sysdate - &&days) l_one,
new   1: select trunc(sysdate - 10) l_one,
old   2:        to_char(trunc(sysdate - &&days), 'yyyy-mm-dd') l_two
new   2:        to_char(trunc(sysdate - 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd') l_two

L_ONE      L_TWO
---------- ----------
03.01.2019 2019-01-03
```

If you want to change its value, **undefine** it first:

```
SQL> undefine days
SQL> /
Enter value for days:
```

Answer (score 0):

Double ampersands "" are used to insert literal values ("literals") into an SQL statement in SqlPlus. Someplace in your script there must be a statement defining literal days. 
Something like

```
DEFINE days = &1
```

or

```
ACCEPT days DEFAULT 0 PROMPT Enter the number of days you forgot to start this script (Default 0):
```

If you enter a valid number it will be subtracted from the actual date.
Instead of a number you could also use a valid SQL Expression that results in a number.

Answer (score -1):

In hour code  & &  mean day of that date must be come otherwise never select date, generally "&&"  is logical operator use as a AND.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/using-scripts-in-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-DAEF8542-1042-4F98-9C68-CED90AC42A79